# Program stops drawing after compiling shaders

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, emscripten, egl

I am working on a C program to be compiled to WASM and display an image in the browser. The point of this program is to learn to set things up using EGL, and therefore I am not interested in any answers involving e.g. SDL, GLFW, etc.

This code works to clear the screen to blue (I've ommitted error checking to reduce size):

```
#include <GLES2/gl2.h>
#include <EGL/egl.h>
#include <EGL/eglext.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "emscripten.h"

struct Environment
{
    EGLint majorVersion;
    EGLint minorVersion;

    EGLDisplay display;
    EGLSurface surface;
};

static struct Environment g_env = {};

bool initGL(struct Environment* env)
{
    env->display = eglGetDisplay(EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY);

    eglInitialize(env->display, &env->majorVersion, &env->minorVersion);

    EGLint numConfigs = 0;
    EGLint attribList[] = 
    {
        EGL_RED_SIZE, 5,
        EGL_GREEN_SIZE, 6,
        EGL_BLUE_SIZE, 5,
        EGL_DEPTH_SIZE, 1,
        EGL_NONE
    };
    EGLConfig config;
    eglChooseConfig(env->display, attribList, &config, 1, &numConfigs);

    env->surface = eglCreateWindowSurface(env->display, config, 0, NULL);

    static const EGLint contextAttribList[] = 
    {
        EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION, 2, EGL_NONE
    };
    EGLContext context = eglCreateContext(env->display, config, EGL_NO_CONTEXT, contextAttribList);


    eglMakeCurrent(env->display, env->surface, env->surface, context);


    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);


    return true;
}

void draw()
{
    glViewport(0, 0, 300, 150);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    eglSwapBuffers(g_env.display, g_env.surface);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (!initGL(&g_env))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    emscripten_set_main_loop(clearScreen, 0, 1);
    return 0;
}
```

But as soon as I add the following after `glClearColor(...)`, I no longer see a blue screen in the browser:

```
const GLuint vertex_shader = load_shader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, VERTEX_SHADER);
const GLuint fragment_shader = load_shader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, FRAGMENT_SHADER);
```

I suspect the shader code is not at all relevent to the problem, but just in case, here is the code for `load_shader`, taken from the [OpenGL ES 2 book](https://github.com/danginsburg/opengles-book-samples/blob/master/LinuxX11/Chapter_2/Hello_Triangle/Hello_Triangle.c) (error checking ommitted)

```
GLuint load_shader ( GLenum type, const char *shaderSrc )
{
   GLuint shader;
   GLint compiled;

   // Create the shader object
   shader = glCreateShader ( type );

   // Load the shader source
   glShaderSource ( shader, 1, &shaderSrc, NULL );

   // Compile the shader
   glCompileShader ( shader );

   // Check the compile status
   glGetShaderiv ( shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compiled );

   return shader;
}
```

And the shaders themselves:

```
char VERTEX_SHADER[] =  
  "attribute vec4 vPosition;    \n"
  "void main()                  \n"
  "{                            \n"
  "   gl_Position = vPosition;  \n"
  "}                            \n";

char FRAGMENT_SHADER[] =  
  "precision mediump float;\n"\
  "void main()                                  \n"
  "{                                            \n"
  "  gl_FragColor = vec4 ( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );\n"
  "}
```

Here is how I compile:

```
EMSCRIPTEN_OPTS = \
-s WASM=1 \
-s FULL_ES2=1 \
-s MODULARIZE=1
${EMCC} main_web.c -o hello.js ${EMSCRIPTEN_OPTS}
```

`glGetError()` is not returning an error code.

And here is my HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
<p id="output" />
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<script type="application/javascript" src="hello.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript">
    Module({
        canvas: (() => document.getElementById('canvas'))(),
        print: (() => {
            var element = document.getElementById('output');
            return function(text) {
                element.innerHTML += text + "<br>";
            };
        })()
    })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Why do I stop clearing the screen when I just load the shaders?

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce the issue. Did you try to add a version specification to the 1st line of the shader code? `#version 100 es`. What is the version? Print the result of `glGetString(GL_VERSION)` respectively `glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION)`, after `eglMakeCurrent`.

Comment: @Rabbid76 My shaders fail to compile when I add that line (`'es': unexpected token). They do compile with `#version 100`, but no change. `GL_VERSION` is `OpenGL ES 2.0 (WebGL 1.0)`, `GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION` is `OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.00 (WebGL GLSL ES 1.0)`

Comment: The version is as expected. As I mention I can't reproduce the issue. The code works fine for me (microsoft windows edge).

Comment: @Rabbid76 Thanks for the help. I just solved it. There's something with how I set up my HTML where printing to stdout adds text to some element in a way that prevents the canvas from rendering. When I stop printing stuff the problem goes away. Can't believe I sacrificed 500 rep to something so silly....

Comment: So you should answer your own question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the HTML. When printing to stdout, the inline  element was interefering with the block `<canvas>` element.

Problem solved by wrapping `<p id="output"/>` in a div.